# Event Driven Future<V> - Thread Pool

Tags: java, multithreading, callable

We use `callable<V>` and `Future<V>` to receive the result of a terminated thread from a thread pool. We should call `get()` to receive the returned result. My problem is: it is not event driven. Is there any framework to get result like `SIGCHLD` for child processes in C?
I want something like this:(the thread pool will call this function when each thread in the pool finished the job)

```
public void fetchResult(Thread t, Runnable r, Future<Integer> result) {
    Integer x = result.get();
    /* handle x */
    /* also we have Thread and Runnable object that has terminated */
}
```

Comment: Can you please express it more? It is still not clear what you exactly want

Comment: What part of "event-driven" is important to you? I'm assuming that it is not the lack of busy-waiting, since Future.get() doesn't busy-wait.

Comment: @Avi: It doesn't busy-wait but it locks. I don't want to lock. I want main thread do some job. when a thread from pool terminates the pool calls a function and in that function when I call `Future.get()` it returns immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might want to check out the [ThreadPoolExecutor.afterExecute()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#afterExecute%28java.lang.Runnable,%20java.lang.Throwable%29) method.  it's called after each task completes.  you could create a custom subclass of ThreadPoolExecutor which has the event based callback behavior you desire.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily create an event driven template. The following *pseudo-code* illustrates one approach.

```
abstract class EventTemplate<T> implements Runnable {
    private BlockingQueue<T> queue; 

    public void submit(Callable<T> callable) {
        queue.add(callable);
    }

    public abstract void handleEvent(T t);

    public void run() {
        for(;;) handleEvent(queue.take());
    }

    public void start() {
         new Thread(this).start();
    }
}
```

Classes can the extend the template

```
class FooEventHandler extends EventTemplate<Foo> {
    public void handleEvent(Foo foo) {
        // do something 
    }
}
```

Which can be instantiated

```
new FooEventHandler().start();
```

Comment: where does the Callable actually get executed?